# Elasticsear _search, is possible to do that?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to return only content that do match with a specific field value and not return the rest  data of document... I mean, I try to realize a filter over data of document... but I can't yet. In sql is so easy, but in ES I still don't understand xD

So this is a image of the query and the document to explain better:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/470hB.png)

Query code:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "params.show": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "childs",
                        "query": {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "childs.params",
                                "query": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": {
                                            "match": {
                                                "childs.params.show": true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried using `must_not` clause in the nested query part ?

Comment: Yes. But I get the same result. It does not remove the object containing "show": false